# Search and replace string in folder shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm using the below script to search and replace string in a folder. How can i modify the code to read 
read multiple $searchname and $replacename from a text file and replace the words in original folders?

here are the folders:

```
main folder: /USERS/path/to/test/
```

inside **test** folder :

```
data.txt   original/  script.sh  tmp/
```

inside **original** folder :

```
file1.txt file2.php ...........
```

inside **data.txt**:

```
a1 a2
b1 b2
c1 c2
```

script for search and replace:

```
 !/bin/bash

 FOLDER="/Users/path/to/test/original/"
 echo "******************************************"
 echo enter word to replace
 read searchterm
 echo enter word that replaces
 read replaceterm



   for file in $(grep -l -R $searchterm $FOLDER) 


      do

   sed -e "s/$searchterm/$replaceterm/g" $file > /Users/path/to/test/tmp/tempfile.tmp 
       mv /Users/path/to/test/tmp/tempfile.tmp $file

       echo "Modified: " $file

    done




   echo " *** All Done! *** "
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As an aside, you can `sed -i -e "s/$search/$replace/g" $file` to do the `sed` in-place, meaning no need to `> tempfile` and rename.

Comment: Thanks but then I have to clean up backup files created (with -e at their ends), how can i send modified files to a new folder? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup the file of search and replace terms (i'm going to call it search_and_replace.txt) to look like:

```
searchone/replaceone
searchtwo/replacetwo
foo/bar
...
```

Then your bash script becomes:

```
!/bin/bash

FOLDER="/Users/path/to/test/original/"

while read line; do
    for file in `find $FOLDER -type f`; do
        sed -i -e "s/$line/g" $file
    done
done < search_and_replace_terms.txt
```

No need to pre-search with grep I think.

Comment: I did as you suggested but the code worked only for the first line in search_and_replace_terms.txt

Comment: I'm guessing you only had two lines in the file. Try adding a newline to the end of the file. Sometimes if there's no end-of-line, only an end-of-file, the last line gets read but read exists with an error.

Comment: You were right. I added a new line and it worked liked a charm. Thank you very much. Would you please tell me how can I get rid of files ending with -e or -e-e ?